# Removing whitespace around image matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following code:

```
def output(pixels):
    plt.imshow(np.reshape(test1, (450, 450), order='F'), cmap=cm.gray)
    for p in range(0,len(pixels),4):
        row1 = pixels[p]
        col1 = pixels[p+1]
        row2 = pixels[p+2]
        col2 = pixels[p+3]
        y = np.linspace(row1,row2,10)
        x = np.linspace(col1,col2,10)
        plt.plot(x, y, color='yellow')
```

It outputs correctly however i am left with lots of whitespace between the image and the axis i wish to remove.
Any help much appreciated, thanks

Comment: create working example (with some data) so we could run it and see this space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need a loglog plot?

For example, if you use a simple plot.

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
def output(pixels):
    test1 = np.arange(450*450)
    plt.imshow(np.reshape(test1, (450, 450), order='F'), cmap='RdGy')
    for p in range(0,len(pixels),4):
        row1 = pixels[p]
        col1 = pixels[p+1]
        row2 = pixels[p+2]
        col2 = pixels[p+3]
        y = np.linspace(row1,row2,10)
        x = np.linspace(col1,col2,10)
        plt.plot(x, y, color='yellow')


pixels = np.arange(128*128)
output(pixels)
```

[image: simple plot]

But, if you use loglog axis.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def output(pixels):
    test1 = np.arange(450*450)
    plt.imshow(np.reshape(test1, (450, 450), order='F'), cmap='RdGy')
    for p in range(0,len(pixels),4):
        row1 = pixels[p]
        col1 = pixels[p+1]
        row2 = pixels[p+2]
        col2 = pixels[p+3]
        y = np.linspace(row1,row2,10)
        x = np.linspace(col1,col2,10)
        plt.loglog(x, y, color='yellow')


pixels = np.arange(128*128)
output(pixels)
```

[image: loglog plot]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but got this error UserWarning: Images are not supported on non-linear axes.
  warnings.warn("Images are not supported on non-linear axes.")

Comment: What did you use and got this message?Did you use my above code with plt.loglog? What data did you use for pixels and test1?